# Is Zlatopramen lemon 1.9% still available in the Czech Republic?

Tags: distribution

I am wondering if the Zlatopramen lemon 1.9% is still available in the Czech Republic (in supermarkets, liquor stores, bars et cetera).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, it is available

You can even get it delivered to your door for [14,90 Kč per 400ml can](https://nakup.itesco.cz/groceries/cs-CZ/products/2001130525921).